# Flatlist won't scroll; cells rendering with extra space

Tags: react-native

I'm having this very strange problem. When I render a list of products with a `FlatList`, it's putting this giant space between my cells. (I've commented out the background image to speed loading, but it behaves the same either way)

#### ProductsListScreen.js

```js
class ProductsListScreen extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return <WithFlatList products={this.props.products} />;
   // return <WithMap products={this.props.products} />;
  }
}

export default connect(({ productsReducer }) => ({
  products: Object.values(productsReducer.products)
}))(ProductsListScreen);

const WithFlatList = ({ products }) => {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={products}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <ProductListCellView product={item} />}
      keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}`}
    />
  );
};

const WithMap = ({ products }) => {
  return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
      {products.map(p => (
        <ProductListCellView product={p} key={p.id} />
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    height: "100%"
  }
};
```

#### ProductsListCellView.js

```
const ProductListCellView = ({ product }: Props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.cellContainer}>
      <ImageBackground
        // source={{ uri: product.images[0].src }}
        style={styles.backgroundImage}
        imageStyle={styles.imageStyle}
      >
        <View style={styles.textContainer}>
          <NameText> {product.name} </NameText>
          <PriceText> ${product.price} </PriceText>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
};
export default ProductListCellView;

const styles = {
  cellContainer: {
    borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
    borderBottomColor: "grey",
    width: "100%",
    height: "50%",
    borderWidth: 3,
    backgroundColor: "lightblue"
  },
  backgroundImage: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  imageStyle: {
    height: "140%",
    width: "140%",
    left: "-20%",
    top: "-20%"
  },
  textContainer: {
    backgroundColor: "black",
    maxWidth: "50%",
    padding: 5,
    opacity: 0.75
  }
};
const baseSize = 14;
const text = {
  name: {
    fontSize: baseSize + 8,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "white"
  },
  price: { fontSize: baseSize + 4, color: "white" }
};
const NameText = props => <Text style={text.name}>{props.children}</Text>;
const PriceText = props => <Text style={text.price}>{props.children}</Text>;
```

[image]

It seems that whatever I set the `height` for `cellContainer` at, it renders the cell at that % of the screen (or of some container that seems based on screen height), and then the cell contents at the same % of the cell.

Also, the list isn't scrolling. I can see the next cell peeking out the bottom so the whole list is rendering, but it just bounces back when I try to scroll. I've tried wrapping various things in `ScrollView` with no luck. (I changed the `cellContainer` height to 15% in the screenshot below)

When I map the items manually (switching the return in the above code to use `, the height works fine, but the scrolling still doesn't work:

[image]

Has anybody else had this problem?

Comment: Not sure why it isn't scrolling, but I would recommend not setting the `cellContainer` height and instead using padding to size it, or a fixed height instead of a %

Comment: That fixed the scrolling as well! Submit this as an answer and I'll be happy to select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than setting the `height` of `cellContainer` to a % value, set it to a static `height`, or using `padding` to automatically size each item.